# Get a particular line of code executed "No Matter What"

Tags: php, error-handling

**Below is the code that throws some errors while getting executed. What I'm trying to do is the last line of the code gets executed no matter what (Error or no Error).**

```
<?php
require 'main.php';
function create_photo($file_path) {
  # Upload the received image file to Cloudinary 
  @$result = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($file_path, array(
    "tags" => "backend_photo_album",
  ));
  @unlink($file_path);
  error_log("Upload result: " . \PhotoAlbum\ret_var_dump($result));
  $photo = \PhotoAlbum\create_photo_model($result);
  return $result;
}
$files = $_FILES["files"];
$files = is_array($files) ? $files : array($files);
$files_data = array();
foreach ($files["tmp_name"] as $index => $value) {
  array_push($files_data, create_photo($value));
}
?>
<script>window.location.replace('index.html')</script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You should read on error handling.. [_try..catch..finally.._](https://athos.blogs.balabit.com/2011/02/try-catch-finally-in-php/)

Comment: @PeeHaa , STFU Operator ?  O.o

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Comment: @PeeHaa, I know they are _error suppression/control operators_ , didn't see STFU keyword anywhere on the manual though.

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Nothing in the official statement on that page but if you scroll down then you cab see STFU. And a wild guess it stands for SHUT THE F**K UP .

Comment: @sanki, lol so whenever you use the `@` operator , you just keep that keyword on your mind , **so you will never ever use that** :P

Comment: @PeeHaa: Would you like to share how should I go with the redirection part that would make the code Optimal.

Comment: @sanki, Why not try with PHPs native [`header()`](http://in1.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php#refsect1-function.header-parameters) for the redirection ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Fair enough BTW do you have any Idea why would using Javascript for redirection will enhance the processing time.

Comment: @sanki, It's not about process time .. what if the client browser doesn't support JS ? Won't your code be stranded ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran: Absolutely right, I didn't even thought of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think depending on your php version, you can use a "try/catch/finally" bloc like that:

```
try
{
     // code that may throw an exception
}
catch(Exeption $e) // The exception you want to catch
{
     // Exception treatment
}
finally
{
     // Executed no matter what
}
```

Maybe take a look about how to use that.